# Left item has a constant width and the right part scales based on the page

Tags: html, css

I never thought this was difficult to do, I think im missing the whole point and forgot a part but the question is pretty simple.

Currently I'm creating a single page application and there are 2 big elements, a menu of the left and everything else on the right (just like a dashboard!).

My page has to be something like:

```
.menu { width:300px } .content { width:100% - 300px}
```

Is this possible so easy or do I need to position the content absolute and give it a margin-left of 300px, in my head it just feels wrong to use a trick like that. Is there a better option or is that the way to go?

Comment: You need not have `position absolute`. Just have `margin-left` and `float none` whuich would do the trick

Comment: Do u have any example like : on jsfiddle

Comment: I can create one ofcourse, moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're close. You just need to use the CSS calc method:
>
> `.menu { width:300px } .content { width: calc(100% - 300px) }`

Calc is a point. But don't forget about crossbrowser support. Add:

```
.content { 
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Comment: I get this error when using it in my own project
      width: calc(-200%); with a stripe through it.

In my css I just divine   width: calc(100% - 300px); it should get the width from the body to use but apparently my chrome doesn't like it

Comment: Webkit browsers haven't needed the prefixed version for a long time. I think it's safe to use the spec version.

Comment: Ye, I noticed my problem already im using currently Less in my project and less had the idea it has to do it's own calculation with it. But I got it fixed with   width: calc(~'100% - 300px');

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You just need to use the CSS `calc` method:

```
.menu { width:300px } .content { width: calc(100% - 300px) }
```

Comment: Is calc really a think, never knew there was something like that.

Comment: Yeah! It's part of the CSS3 spec with really good browser support now.

Comment: Yes, works perfect. This was the way I was thinking in my head, the margin-left technique just feels kinda wonky to use.  (if wonky is a word). Here is it in action http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/ZQWXVJ !

Comment: Well, it gives an error in my browser but on codepen it works fine. If I put in my code editor and display it to the page it errors, but when I use the same code in my inspect element inside the browser it gives the result I want. strange